# Difference between values based on condition in column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to achieve something like this

```
Index   Reading Status          Difference
1         R1    Valid           N/A
2         R2    Valid           R3-R1
3         R3    Valid           R4-R2
4         R4    Valid           R5-R3
5         R5    Valid           R6-R4
6         R6    Valid           R7-R5
7         R7    Valid           R8-R6
8         R8    Valid           R9-R7
9         R9    Valid           R11-R8
10       R10    Invalid         R11-R9
11       R11    Valid           R14-R12
12       R12    Valid           R15-R13
13       R13    Valid           R16-R14
14       R14    Valid           R17-R15
15       R15    Valid           R18-R16
16       R16    Valid           R19-R17
17       R17    Valid           R20-R18
18       R18    Valid           N/A
19       R19    Valid           N/A
20       R20    Valid           N/A
```

For `R10` since the status is Invalid, we do not consider that reading and is no longer consecutive to R9.
Currently, I have written the following code, but unable to incorporate the `Invalid` status within this -

```
InputDataSet = read.csv(text="Id    Index   Reading Status
100 1   247.8160816 Valid
100 2   227.9605826 Valid
100 3   261.989589  Valid
100 4   298.6593195 Valid
100 5   325.9248677 Valid
100 6   352.7870118 Valid
100 7   368.2022031 Valid
100 8   370.2106412 Valid
100 9   383.0108577 Valid
100 10  389.3365793 Valid
100 11  402.4572303 Valid
100 12  30.93910164 Invalid
100 13  397.1242836 Valid
100 14  403.796189  Valid
100 15  406.9261481 Valid
100 16  410.2277685 Valid
100 17  410.2392126 Valid
100 18  406.285279  Valid
100 19  408.9860846 Valid
100 20  409.7499777 Valid
100 21  409.2378546 Valid
101 1   407.3953558 Valid
101 2   408.9460303 Valid
101 3   407.1378638 Valid
101 4   407.4611594 Valid
101 5   406.7687918 Valid
101 6   406.5570761 Valid
101 7   404.4341971 Valid
101 8   404.1194846 Valid
101 9   404.6974113 Valid
101 10  403.6273887 Valid
101 11  403.4271171 Valid
101 12  403.1066825 Valid
101 13  406.2681128 Valid
101 14  403.790467  Valid
101 15  404.5057227 Valid
101 16  405.535691  Valid
101 17  406.6429068 Valid
101 18  407.1264197 Valid
101 19  410.785668  Valid
101 20  414.6680761 Valid
101 21  421.4372562 Valid
101 22  428.6041186 Valid
101 23  441.3614197 Valid
101 24  455.9583586 Valid
101 25  465.6457821 Valid
101 26  476.6178049 Valid
101 27  484.2939294 Valid
101 28  492.8483878 Valid
", sep="")


r = order( InputDataSet$Id, InputDataSet$Index)
InputDataSet = InputDataSet[r,]

library(dplyr)

OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Diff = (round(lead(Reading),2)-round(lag(Reading),2)))
```

Edit -
`R11` gets `R14-R12` because, first we calculate `R11` as `R12-R10` and then drop the rows that used `R10` for their calculation as `R10` is `Invalid`. In this case, Difference for `R9` and `R11` will be dropped as they use `R10` for their calculation. You don't drop the value, rather you drop the calculation that uses the value. Refer to the above image.

Comment: Can you create a MWE with the data you started with?

Comment: Since I'm inferring that your `R3 - R1` means you want to subtract a number associated with the `R1` row from a number associated with the `R3` row, as geek45 said, _we need to see numbers. Further, for `R9`, I would have expected the difference to be either `R11-R8` (since `R10` is invalid) or something else entirely, but instead you have it subtracting `R11-R9`. If this is truly correct, please give other rules and caveats to your otherwise under-defined logic here.

Comment: @r2evans - Difference calculation that uses `R10` value will be ignored – so out of 7 readings, if reading 4 's status is Invalid then, the difference calculated from reading 4 (blocks 3 and 5) will be ignored, and the difference calculated for blocks 2, 4, and 6 will now be considered “consecutive”.

Comment: @geek45 Added MWE with some data points.

Comment: It seems as if the new "Consecutive Diff" column is not actually rowwise paired with the frame itself, is that right? That is, the 10th value of `Diff` is not necessarily matched with the 10th value of `Reading`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't quit get the logic (e.g., why is row 11 calculated as R14 - R12 and not R12 - R9?). However, if it is just about incorporating the Status column, you can adjust the amount of lead and lag depending on whether either lead(Status) or lag(Status) are invalid:

```
useStatus <- df %>%
  mutate(first = ifelse(lead(Status) == "Valid", paste(lead(Reading)), paste(lead(Reading, 2))), 
         second = ifelse(lag(Status) == "Valid", paste(lag(Reading)), paste(lag(Reading, 2))),
         diff = ifelse(is.na(second) | is.na(first), NA, paste(first, "-", second)))
```

You can now adjust the second clause of the `ifelse` statement to suit your logic. You could also of course do this in one go, but it is easier to understand with the helper columns (first & second). The above code will provide the desired results for rows 9 and 10. It will not for the row after because I don't quite get the logic there.

So apparently you want to just delete the rows that are based on an invalid other row. You could just then do:

```
useStatus <- df %>%
  mutate(Diff = paste(lead(Reading), "-", lag(Reading)))

stringVector = useStatus$Diff
invalid_rows = df$Reading[df$Status == "Invalid"]
delete_elements = grep(invalid_rows, stringVector)
stringVector = stringVector[-c(delete_elements)]

useStatus$diff_new = c(stringVector, rep(NA, length(delete_elements)))
```

First row gets the column entries as a character vector. Then you extract the invalid rows and find which rows need to be deleted via grep. Then just delete those elements and insert them into your data frame.

Comment: thanks - R11 gets R14-R12 because, first we calculate R11 as R12-R10 and then drop the rows that used R10 for their calculation as R10 is Invalid. See the image that I attached to the question.

Comment: I edited my answer. You just need to find which rows to delete from the column, and then reinsert this column into your dataframe.